# How to calculate values based on different columns in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tables like

| order_id | date | price_local_currency | local_currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2022-04-10 | 12.3 | EUR |
| 123457 | 2022-04-10 | 131.2 | USD |

and

| date | GBP | EUR | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-10 | 1.0 | 1.12 | 1.15 |
| 2022-04-10 | 1.0 | 1.11 | 1.16 |

So I need to join them on date and calculate `price_pounds` column. How can I calculate it using different columns? Of course there are a lot more than just 2 currencies, in fact I have all of them.

Comment: Attach your output need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with flatten_rates as (
  select date, arr[offset(0)] as local_currency, cast(arr[offset(1)] as float64) as exchange_rate
  from pound_rates t, 
  unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
  where not arr[offset(0)] = 'date'
)
select o.*, 
  round(price_local_currency * exchange_rate, 2) as price_pounds 
from orders o
join flatten_rates 
using(date, local_currency)
```

if to apply to sample/dummy data as in your question

```
with orders as (
  select 123456 order_id, '2022-04-10' date, 12.3 price_local_currency, 'EUR' local_currency union all
  select 123457, '2022-04-10', 131.2, 'USD'
), pound_rates as (
  select '2022-04-10' date, 1.0 GBP, 1.12 EUR, 1.15 USD union all
  select '2022-04-11', 1.0, 1.11, 1.16 
)
```

the output is

[image]